# I changed the code while it was running and it had effects on the output?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.
I ran my test and while it was going on I changed something in the code from IDE, and those changes are not supposed to have any effect on the running test because it's already compiled, but the test failed when it got to the point that I changed throwing errors **related to the changes** !!!!!

By the way, that change was adding a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many IDE's automatically plug in the new code for running aps when a change is made, sometimes even warning that the app needs to be restarted if the IDE thinks change is too drastic. I don't know about Selenium, but Eclipse does this.

Comment: and I use Eclipse :| So thanks for your answer, and just one more question, what was wrong with my question that  got a downvote?

Comment: Life is not fair buddy.

Comment: Some people here just down vote even when they don't understand the problem or don't know the answer.

Comment: @AGill so if you found my question useful please upvote it :)

Comment: @LoveJavaTwo I can't guess the motives of other people, but: (1) you didn't provide complete information, (2) you assumed something about your environment that you probably shouldn't need to (e.g., you've probably been making changes and running the browser manually and seeing the differences in behavior--so obviously it's hot-deploying).